# Python Form a List based from the values in dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

i'm new to python 
I have Ordered dictionary

```
dictA = {f1 : ["s","r"], 
        f2 : ["p"], 
        f3 : ["w","t"]}
```

How do I form a list that should have only 1st elements from values present in dictionary dictA
and followed by 2nd elements ... and so on, until it reached the `list_size_limit = 5`

```
Final list ["s","p","w","r","t"]
```

if the `list_size_limit = 3`

```
Final list = ["s","p","w"]
```

How do i form a list which has 1st elements of all values of dictionary to be present in list 1st,  followed by 2nd elements...3rd elements

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? Note that you can't guarantee output order of values from a dictionary, it's not clear whether you need that.

Comment: There's an inherent problem with this question. Dictionaries are unordered on their keys, so `list` with `list_size_limit == 3` could be any permutation of `{"s", "p", "w"}`. [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) can help with that at least.

Comment: i have Orderdict() dictA is ordered

Comment: I need all the 1st elements of all values of dictionary to be present in list 1st,  followed by 2nd elements...3rd elements

Comment: "i have Orderdict() dictA is ordered" Please add this to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dictA = {"f1" : ["m"],
        "f2" : ["p","y","o","a","s","d","f","g"],
        "f3" : ["w","t"],
         "f5" : ["z","x"],
         "f6" : ["c","v"]}

result = []
limit_size = 3
values_list = []
for values in dictA.itervalues():
    values_list.append(len(values))

for i in range(0,max(values_list)):
    keys = list(dictA.keys())
    count = 0
    while count < len(keys):
        try:
            result.append(dictA[keys[count]][i])
        except IndexError:
            dictA.pop(keys[count])
        count = count + 1
print "final ",result[0:limit_size]
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly not sure what to call this function. Naming things is hard.

```
def getFirstOfDictList(d, limit=None):
    if limit is None:
        limit = float('inf')
    done = 0
    iters = [iter(i) for i in d.values()]
    items = []
    while iters:
        toRemove = []
        for iterator in iters:
            if done >= limit:
                return items
            try:
                items.append(next(iterator))
                done += 1
            except StopIteration:
                toRemove.append(iterator)
        for finishedIterator in toRemove:
            iters.remove(finishedIterator)
    return items
```

Comment: any alternative way to solve ? With out creating iter object